# How to create a custom time selection control for android that looks like like apple's ring?

Tags: android

I want to create a custom selection control for my android app. The thing is that it should look like the time ring in apple's product that can be seen in this picture

---

[image: for instance].

---

When a user click and hold the ring he can move it and by that increase / decrease an int number. Do you familiar with any look alike control?

Thanks!

The answer to my question is this [link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/534/android-ui-making-an-analog-rotary-knob/)

Comment: don't. just don't. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: First, I did do it, because this is the look and feel the designers wanted for my app. You can observe the result here: http://goo.gl/wy7nz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it s like iphone date picker. Try that : https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/